# Using an If statement, produces runtime-13 type mismatch error

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, type-mismatch

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ''Dim rCell As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rNext As Range

'loop through the cells in column A of the source sheet
For Each rCell In Sheet4.Range("A3:U25")
'loop as many times as the value in column U of the source sheet
    For i = 1 To rCell.Offset(0, 23).Value
        'find the next empty cell to write to in the dest sheet
        Set rNext = Sheet12.Cells(Sheet12.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        'copy A and B from source to the dest sheet
        rCell.Resize(1, 23).Copy
        rNext.Resize(1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Next i
Next rCell
End Sub
```

1. I'm getting a runtime-13 type mismatch at line `For i = 1 To rCell.Offset(0, 23).Value` .
   When it errors, I click end and it works fine. Don't want to have to click end.
2. In my form I'm using an If statement `=IF(E4>0,1,"")` to produce the 1 needed. If I remove the If statement and manually put the 1 in place then it works without errors.

Comment: Can you add a brief description of what you are trying to achieve so that it is easier to put your code in context?

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because the ending range in your FOR LOOP is not a type of LONG.

If I'm reading your second bullet point correctly, I think your IF statement is off.  Instead of =IF(E4>0,1,""), the FALSE criteria of the IF should be numeric (e.g. =IF(E4>0,1,**2**).

You can verify by putting the following statement above the problem FOR LOOP:

```
Debug.Assert IsNumeric(rCell.Offset(0, 23).Value)
```

This will stop the code from executing and you can put this in the immediate window to see what the value is and the location of the cell in question:

```
? rCell.Offset(0, 23).Value
? rCell.Offset(0, 23).Column
? rCell.Offset(0, 23).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed the problem:

`=IF(E4>0,1,"")` needs to be `=IF(E4>0,1,0)`

Cannot look for a blank, has to be a 1 or 0. or numeric value as you said.
Simple enough. Thanks for the help. Didn't even see that.